# Contact cement for foundation dimple board

Tags: foundation, waterproofing

I have a cinder block foundation and plan on excavating to apply a 3 layered approach toward waterproofing it.

1. Paint on asphalt sealer (aka tar) - [Henry 101](https://www.homedepot.com/p/100003547)
2. Bituthene adhesive membrane (similar to ice/water shield) -  [Grace Bituthene 4000](https://www.homedepot.com/p/202935713)
3. HDPE dimple board - unsure which brand i'll buy, but here's an example - [DMX AG](https://www.homedepot.com/p/310516641)  It will be installed with the points facing the wall (smooth side facing out).

Since i'm doubling up on sealant technology with the asphalt and the adhesive membrane I'd really like to not puncture it by nailing/tapConning the dimple board to the wall.  I saw that the Delta system has [adhesive spikes](https://www.dorken.com/en/our-products/accessories/accessories/delta-grip-fastener.php) you can use (can't seem to find a place to buy them, I've seen the ballpark at 100 for $250), and then i saw that PolyWall offers a [sprayable adhesive](https://youtu.be/H3gnu1CR3Gw?t=168) for their dimple board ($600 per cylinder!).  That made me wonder..  Would regular [contact cement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076CC97F9) work ($150 for 5gal)?  The kind that you typically use for adhering a countertop laminate to the substrate is what i had in mind.  I assume it really only has to hold the dimple board on the wall until the backfill is in place.. but perhaps it needs to also withstand future frost heaving forces?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Comment: @freeman Thus far i only received one answer and it didn't address any of the primary points of the question so i cannot mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Why waste money on adhesive. The nailing is only required over the flat tap (see DMX AG installation guide) on the top to keep it in place (if I am not mistaken). As you have already known, the backfill will then be pushing the sheet against the wall. Just pay attention to the backfill material, it should not contain anything with sharp edges/points that may puncture the dimple sheet. The sheet will not be moved by frost heave, provides the flat tap is set firmly in place (note, any adhesive may separate from the wall after certain amount of time, and fail the purpose of water proofing.

Comment: because those nails at the top of the sheet penetrate the concrete block, thus potentially allowing water to enter the block at those points, defeating the purpose of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

We had a dimple board, well came on a roll so started one corner round to the other on 3 sides so no breaks at all.

We used a 2*1 to secure it to the wall at the top and allowed some extra which was pulled up as we back filled

Once the filling was complete the 2*1 was removed and only a few screw holes were left in a place that makes no difference.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing your approach, but this answer doesn't seem to address the primary concerns of the topic: not puncturing the sealant layers with fasteners, will contact cement work, long-term stability of the sheet without mechanical fasteners holding it in place.

Comment: Well ours is held in olace by friction, which is not $150/gallon and has been there 15 years.

Comment: Thanks, the 15 year point helps reduce concerns at least about stability without fasteners.